# Is there any validity to the correlation between fluid intelligence and frequency of hand gestures in verbal communication?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

**Question**: Is there any conclusive research showing any significant correlation with the above pair of variables? If there is a correlation, what other more significant covariate could perhaps be confounding the relationship? Is it perhaps confounded by the fact that individuals with higher intelligence are better abstract thinkers (or at least have a higher tendency to abstract) are thus are more likely to use hand gestures as a way to abstract their thoughts?

**Abstract**: Humans use hand gestures to organize their abstract thoughts more coherently into language during dialogical communication.

**Research**: [Gestures](https://sites.bu.edu/ombs/2011/10/24/put-your-hands-up-for-intelligence/) are processed in the same areas of the brain as speech (think sign language): the left inferior frontal gyrus (Broca’s) and the posterior middle temporal gyrus (Wenicke’s area). Further, the left hemisphere is also heavily linked to abstraction and fluid intelligence. [According to David Geary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence#Fluid%20intelligence%20and%20working%20memory), gf and gc can be traced to two separate brain systems. Fluid intelligence involves both the dorsolateral prefrontal cortex (left hemisphere), the anterior cingulate cortex (left hemisphere), and other systems related to attention and short-term memory.  [It has been demonstrated](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4865523/) that speakers with higher fluid intelligence produce more gestures from non-egocentric (O-VPT) views than speakers with average fluid intelligence on a task involving visual imagery (Sassenberg, Foth, Wartenburger, & van der Meer, 2011). Because Parkinson's Disease (PD) causes mild cognitive impairment in most patients, PD patients might produce fewer O-VPT gestures than controls, who would likely have higher fluid intelligence.